# How can the <html> be the INP penalty element?

Tags: interaction-to-next-paint

I have set a very low internet speed, to 20kbps.

And when I try to click on a `<i>` element on the page, due to the low speed, the js event handler of that `<i>` is not loaded yet (on the bottom of the page). It has caused an INP. However, the target in INP report is not the `<i>` element but the `html`.

How can it be like this? This is local data and in my RUM I saw a lot of `html` as the element from my real users. How can I find the exact element that the users failed to click?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another example of `html` and `body` elements showing up in INP attribution data:

[image]

This is totally normal and it can happen when a user interacts with no particular UI elements on the page. For example, if they click on the background or use the keyboard when nothing is focused.

But if they click on a part of the UI, I'd expect that to be the event target. Event listeners don't need to be attached for the target to be set, or for slow INP to occur for that matter. So I'm not sure what's happening in your case but to answer the general question, it's not unexpected for the `html` element to appear in your attribution data.

Comment: So if the user clicks on the background (not even selecting a text, just a random click) and the CPU is running 100%, the INP score will be recorded?

Comment: Yes exactly, which is why it's really important not to have any long tasks at all, because those could be the cause of INP for innocuous interactions like these

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like it's quite challenging because sometimes I need to do a lot of DOM modifications, though I have showed "Loading..." text on the screen, I can't force/persuade the users not to click at all.

Comment: It's ok to do a lot of (necessary) work, but the trick is to slice it up so that there are no long tasks: https://web.dev/articles/optimize-long-tasks

Comment: Thanks. Do you think implementing some functions like run a task and let the cpu take a few ms rest would help? Is there an API to do that? I desire for a requestIdleQueue-like API that I can push a lot of very small tasks and the CPU will automatically run one until the previous ones are done and it(CPU) took the enough time of rest.